# Google Authentication API empty Widget URL

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to configure Google's Identity Toolkit API, however I'm unable to figure out why my Widget URL is empty and, actually, I don't know where I can register these Widget URLs.

[image: Google Identity Toolkit API Console]

I'm really confused, because Google's documentation ([Identity Toolkit for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service)) is showing how to set up things in the new UI, but every time I open the developer console ([console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/)) I get the old interface, which does not match the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can configure the Widget URL, you need to create a Client ID for Web applications. When creating the Client ID, the redirect URI should be the path at which you will host the Identity Toolkit widget.

By the way, if this is your first time trying Identity Toolkit, it may be useful to begin with one of the [quickstart apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/).

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have created a Google OAuth2 Web client, as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service step 5.

Then in the right panel of the configuration page (i.e. your screenshot), you select the oauth2 web client created in the step above. The configuration page has a bug that may automatically select the Google service account client, which does not contain any redirect URIs.

Now the Widget URL dropdown list will be automatically populated with the redirect URIs belonging to the selected oauth2 web client.